# Flask HTTP Blocking Post Requests from flutter app

Tags: flutter, flask, dart, post

I'm building a backend for my flutter app and I try to post data but it keeps failing
Backend Python(Flask) Code:

```
@app.route("/api/quotes/add/<username>", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def add_quote(username):
    data = request.json["create"]
    try:
        with open(pathes.USERS_DATA_PATH) as f:
            users_data = json.load(f)
            users_data["quotes"][data[f'{username}{users_data["quotes"].length}']
                                 ] = models.User().from_dict(data, username=username)
    except:
        return jsonify({"sc": 0, "data": "Failed to save the quote"})
    else:
        return jsonify({"sc": 2, data: None})
```

Flutter Post Code:

```
postQuote(Map map) async {
  try {
    await http.post("http://10.0.2.2:5000/api/quotes/UserOne", body: {
      "create": convert.json.encode(map),
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: What's the error code ? If your flask application is using flask CSRF protection plugin and you're not passing the CSRF token in your post function the POST request won't go through.

Comment: I have not enable any Protection yet

Comment: There is no Error msgs but ```127.0.0.1 - - [13/Nov/2020 07:09:50] "POST /api/quotes/UserOne HTTP/1.1" 405 -```

Comment: You have a typo in your flutter function. Your flask route is **/api/quotes/add/<username>** but the URL in the postQuote function is **api/quotes/UserOne**. You forgot **add**.